# How to load and use PYD files on the kaggle platform

Tags: python, kaggle, pyd

I want to use a function in python, but this function is not open source, the function needs to use the PYD file, but on kaggle, I don't know how to load this PYD file, so I can't use this function.

can be able to successfully use the function

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.